# Clang's UBSan & Function Pointer: Is this illegal?

Tags: c++, linux, clang, shared-libraries, ubsan

I'm trying to call some C++ functions through a function pointer table which is exported as a C symbol from a shared object. The code is actually working but Clang's undefined behavior sanitizer (= UBSan) sees the call I made is illegal as follows:

```
==11410==WARNING: Trying to symbolize code, but external symbolizer is not initialized!
path/to/HelloWorld.cpp:25:13: runtime error: call to function (unknown) through pointer to incorrect function type 'foo::CBar &(*)()'
(./libFoo.so+0x20af0): note: (unknown) defined here
```

Due to Clang's undefined behavior sanitizer, it is legal to indirectly call a function which returns a reference of a C++ standard class object through a function pointer **but it's illegal for a user-defined class. Somebody could you please tell me what's wrong with it?**

I've been trying to build the project on **Ubuntu 14.04** with **Clang-llvm 3.4-1ubuntu3** and **CMake 2.8.12.2**. To reproduce the phenomenon, please place the following **5 files** in the same directory and invoke build.sh. It will create a makefile and build the project, and run the executable.

**Foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include <string>

//
#define EXPORT __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))

namespace foo {
    class CBar
    {
        // empty
    };

    class CFoo
    {
    public:
        static CBar& GetUdClass();
        static std::string& GetStdString();
    };

    // function pointer table.
    typedef struct
    {
        CBar& (*GetUdClass)();
        std::string& (*GetStdString)();
    } fptr_t;

    //! function pointer table which is exported.
    extern "C" EXPORT const fptr_t FptrInFoo;
}

#endif
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace foo
{
    // returns reference of a static user-defined class object.
    CBar& CFoo::GetUdClass()
    {
        cout << "CFoo::GetUdClass" << endl;
        return *(new CBar);
    }

    // returns reference of a static C++ standard class object.
    std::string& CFoo::GetStdString()
    {
        cout << "CFoo::GetStdString" << endl;
        return *(new string("Hello"));
    }

    // function pointer table which is to be dynamically loaded.
    const fptr_t FptrInFoo = {
        CFoo::GetUdClass,
        CFoo::GetStdString,
    };
}
```

**HelloWorld.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "Foo.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace foo;

int main()
{
    // Retrieve a shared object.
    const string LibName("./libFoo.so");
    void *pLibHandle = dlopen(LibName.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);
    if (pLibHandle != 0) {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Info: " << LibName << " found at " << pLibHandle << endl;
        // Try to bind a function pointer table:
        const string SymName("FptrInFoo");
        const fptr_t *DynLoadedFptr = static_cast<const fptr_t *>(dlsym(pLibHandle, SymName.c_str()));
        if (DynLoadedFptr != 0) {
            cout << "Info: " << SymName << " found at " << DynLoadedFptr << endl;
            cout << endl;
            // Do something with the functions in the function table pointer.
            DynLoadedFptr->GetUdClass();    // Q1. Why Clang UBSan find this is illegal??
            DynLoadedFptr->GetStdString();  // Q2. And why is this legal??
        } else {
            cout << "Warning: Not found symbol" << endl;
            cout << dlerror() << endl;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "Warning: Not found library" << endl;
        cout << dlerror() << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
project (test)

if(COMMAND cmake_policy)
      cmake_policy(SET CMP0003 NEW)
endif(COMMAND cmake_policy)

set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN")

add_library(Foo SHARED Foo.cpp)

add_executable(HelloWorld HelloWorld.cpp)
target_link_libraries (HelloWorld dl)
```

**build.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# 1. create a build directory.
if [ -d _build ]; then
    rm -rf _build
fi
mkdir _build
cd _build

# 2. generate a makefile.
CC=clang CXX=clang++ CXXFLAGS="-fvisibility=hidden -fsanitize=undefined -O0 -g3" cmake ..

# 3. build.
make

# 4. and run the executable.
./HelloWorld
```

I've been trying to find a clue to dig into the issue and realized the issue was caught by "function" option of the sanitizer (-fsanitize=function) but it's not so much documented. I'd appreciate if you guys could give me a reasonable explanation for such a runtime error message which looks like coming from another planet. Thanks.

**What was Clang pointing out as "unknown" in the output?**

Below is the output from addr2line to check what was "unknown" for the sanitizer:

```
$ addr2line -Cfe _build/libFoo.so 0x20af0
foo::CFoo::GetUdClass()
path/to/Foo.cpp:12
```

Hmm, it really looks like the function I was expecting to call for me. Can you guess how did it look different for Clang?

Comment: `FptrInFoo` is not a function pointer in namespace `foo`, it is a global! The simple reason is that it is declared as `extern "C"`. Try to declare one in a different namespace and you will see. What I'm wondering now is whether the definition will create an object inside the namespace (and with static linkage, because it's a constant) or if it defines the external global. BTW: Why are you using "typedef struct ...", you can't use that code in C anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CBar's `typeinfo` needs to have default visibility for the function's type be considered the same by Clang on Linux across the executable and the dynamic library; change Foo.h to:

```
  class EXPORT CBar
  {
      ...
  }
```

Comment: Nasty. I'wonder if the compiler could be improved to provide a better diagnostic. Good catch Stephan!

Comment: Since I lost a couple of hours on this one, I may add that one should be careful to use `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))` both in the library and in the executable calling it.

Comment: This does not seem to suffice if `CBar` is not polymorphic. I have the problem on `void(SomeEnum, const SomeStruct&, const SomeClass&)`. None of these types are polymorphic, so I don't see where the RTTI for any of these types would be emitted by the compiler. It seems to me that this runs afoul of duplicated type_infos the same way inline exception classes cause headaches: https://marcmutz.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/fun-with-exceptions/

Comment: The RTTI should be emitted wherever needed, weakly if necessary.  And trying with a recent Clang on Linux, that seems to work fine for me: